# EXCEL VBA: Change NUMBER formatting based on value of another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I want to change the formatting of a range of cells `C7:K35` based on the value in Cell `A1`.

When `A1` = 1 the number format should be `"_-* #,##0_-;-* #,##0_-;_-* ""-""??_-;_-@_-"`

When `A1` <> 1 the number format should be `"_-$* #,##0_-;-$* #,##0_-;_-$* ""-""??_-;_-@_-"`

I know this will need to be done in VBA using `case`, as I have done it before when asking on a different forum, but I cannot find the question any more.

Im guessing it would be something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
       case when Range("A1").value = 1 then
       Range("C7:K32").Select
       Selection.NumberFormat = "_-* #,##0_-;-* #,##0_-;_-* ""-""??_-;_-@_-"
       Else
       Range("C7:K32").Select
       Selection.NumberFormat = "_-$* #,##0_-;-$* #,##0_-;_-$* ""-""??_-;_-@_-"
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to `Select` anything except the `Select Case` statement.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
       select case Range("A1").value
           case 1
               Range("C7:K32").NumberFormat = "_-* #,##0_-;-* #,##0_-;_-* ""-""??_-;_-@_-"
           case Else
               Range("C7:K32").NumberFormat = "_-$* #,##0_-;-$* #,##0_-;_-$* ""-""??_-;_-@_-"
        end select
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `If` will be more clear than `Select Case` it seems...

Comment: True, but `Select Case` eases the addition of other options in the future.